# Error while trying to publish asset throw maven command (Mulesoft)

Tags: mule, maven-plugin, mulesoft

I try to push an asset with maven command, only I get this error;

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:exchange-mule-maven-plugin:0.0.15:exchange-pre-deploy (validate) on project json-logger:
```

I also use this plugin to deploy it to exchange.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>exchange-mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exchange-pre-deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exchange-deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The plugin above seems to be mandatory following Mulesoft documentation. Al the user names and passwords are working fine and also the endpoints. Does anybody have any idea why is throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven#publish-an-asset-to-exchange-using-maven) says that `exchange-mule-maven-plugin` should only be used for a custom assets. From the artifact name I'm guessing you are publishing a Mule extension (also known as a connector or module), which the documentation says uses the more usual `mule-maven-plugin`. Be sure to follow the instructions exactly.

If you still have an error execute Maven in debug mode to see more details.

Comment: Thanks again Aled. You are right, so it was combined issue also because my account is using MFA and when I disabled that I was able to push even without the plugin.

Comment: It is recommended to use Connected App authentication for non interactive tasks: https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven#publish-and-consume-federated-assets